# How to Execute Javascript in an AngularRoute View

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am writing a phonegap application using Angular's ngRoute as an MVC. This all works beautifully, except for my top bar which includes the trigger button for the slide out menu. as it sits now, the top bar has the same title for every page, so to fix this I moved the top bar inside of the route view, which now stops my slide out menu from working.

How can i get the javascript trigger to actually run properly inside a route view (i understand this has to do with the page, and all of its JS, rendering before the route view is actually loaded) and I also would LIKE to execute other JS in a route view as well. for example, one of the views handles GPS location and NFC chip reading and i would love to only execute those scripts when that view is active rather than all the time, which chews up battery listening for NFC chips and GeoData even when that view is not in use.

if this isnt possible or is a serious pain then id just as soon go back to conventional page changes instead of views, im just hoping that there is a way to do this.

Here is the relevant code illustrating the issue:

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).load(function() {
        $('#menutoggle').toggle(function() {
            $('#right').animate({
                left: 200
            });
        }, function() {
            $('#right').animate({
                left: 0
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="menu">
<span class="logo-bar"></span>
    <ul id="sidenav">
        <li>
            <a href="#/Checkin">
                <img src="img/home.png">Check In
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/logout">
                <img src="img/logout.png">Logout</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content view-animate-container">
    <div id="contentcontroller" ng-view class="view-animate wrapper">

    </div>
  </div>
```

CheckIn.html

```
<div id="right">
    <div id="menubar">
        <div id="menutoggle">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            Check In
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the toggle button works fine on whatever view is initially loaded, however as soon as a page change occurs the menu toggle simply stops.

is there any way to remedy this?

Comment: As the question is worded right now, it's likely to draw down votes and/or close votes.  You never directly ask an actual question, and you haven't provided any code illustrating your issue, or any examples of your actual and expected results.  Your statement that you are "hoping that there is a way to do this." is at best going to draw "Yes, there is a way" type answers, but gives the impression you are hoping someone will just write code for you.

Comment: Fair enough. i have reworded and added my sample code. i can add screenshots later if necessary

Comment: I don't see any angular related code in this other than the ng-view,  but the approach I would take is to make a separate controller for the topbar, leave the topbar in the main index, and use an expression like `{{pageTitle}}` instead of hard coded text `Check In`.  The jquery you have breaks because it doesn't know that the ui-view destroys the `<div id="right">` and replaces it with another one on page change.

Comment: right i figured as much for the slide out menu the element disappears. From what i have been reading i can also create a controller for a route view and load any view-specific JS in that controller? but documentation isnt really there for getting this to work and loading jquery there simply does not, in fact the application wont load at all once its exported and installed to a device. i thought of using a directive like that so i guess thats what ill go for.

Comment: I will be at a computer in about an hour and a half if you want to talk in chat about what some of the options are...